# Is there a way to detect in code if the Xcode StoreKit testing option is enabled in Schemes->options?

Tags: xcode, storekit

I have followed a guide and succeeded in implementing Xcode StoreKit testing. It works in the simulator and on a device. I was wondering, is there a way to detect in code, in Swift or in Objective-C, at compile or runtime if the Xcode StoreKit testing option is currently enabled ?

[image]

Comment: Out of curiosity: what problem are you trying to solve with that?

Comment: On the simulator,I have no choice, I have to use Xcode storeKit testing. On TestFlight and the App Store, I have no choice, I have to use the sandboxed or production StoreKit respectively. But when running my app from Xcode on a real device, I might decide to stick with Xcode testing, or use Sandboxed testing. In this case, I have to know in code if the user has opted in for Xcode StoreKit Testing in Schemes.

Comment: Your code is supposed to work in the same way regardless of StoreKit configuration file being used. Why do you need the code to know it?

Comment: @VadimBelyaev It's a legit question. My case is that I'm using a third-party StoreKit provider (such as RevenueCat), that does not support StoreKit testing. So it's good to know at compile/runtime to switch to a fallback implementation for testing the rest of the app.

Comment: @Legoless, actually RevenueCat does support StoreKit testing: you can export a certificate from the .storekit file and upload it to RevCat. I've been using it for quite some time and it works great.

Comment: That is why I said "such as RevenueCat", because I am not using RevenueCat, but a less known provider. So switching to a more expensive solution here is really not the solution.